# Adapter not working while implementing RecyclerView and cardview

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement `RecyclerView` and `CardView` and I am working with `json`.
All my code is working fine and `RecyclerView` adapter is also not showing any error.

But in my main activity when i try to call adapter it is showing a error.

I took all the reference from [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465)

**Foodlist.java**

```
public class FoodList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodList.FoodViewHolder>{

    private final Activity context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    public static class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txt1;
        TextView txt2;
        TextView txt3;
        TextView txt4;
        CardView cv;

        FoodViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            txt1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            txt2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
            txt3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
            txt4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt4);
        }
    }

    List<Food> food;
    public FoodList(Activity context, List<Food> food) {
        this.food = food;
        inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.examplelistview, viewGroup, false);
        FoodViewHolder fvh = new FoodViewHolder(v);
        return fvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FoodViewHolder holder, int position) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.examplelistview, null, true);
        if (view == null) {
            holder.txt1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            holder.txt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
            holder.txt3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
            holder.txt4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt4);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        else {
            holder = (FoodViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        final Food item = food.get(position);
        holder.txt1.setText(item.txt1);
        holder.txt2.setText(item.txt2);
        holder.txt3.setText(item.txt3);
        holder.txt4.setText(item.txt4);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return food.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

}
```

**Food.java:**

```
public class Food {
    public String txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4;

}
```

**FoodViewHolder.java**

```
    public class FoodViewHolder {
    TextView txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

final FoodList adapter = new FoodList(MainActivity.this,food);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And I want to call my adapter in `json` below in another function:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

builder.setAdapter(adapter<here it is showing the error>, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
}
```

What should i do?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: First question is, what is the error? The second question is whether the food list given to the adapter is `null`? The third point is that the `onBindViewHolder` method should not inflate views. `onCreateViewHolder` should inflate, while binding simply sets the values.

Comment: @Kevin I am not able to call the adapter in a proper way as i think the error is cannot resolve symbol adapter. Secondly i just forgot to mention this: 'private List<Food> food;'     and third i read from the reference link that onBindViewHolder works same as getView() in listview adapter..

Comment: @Kevin I think i got the error:      Wrong 1st argument type. Found 'com.gampzz.classes.Foodlist' required: 'android.widget.listadapter'